# categorize website based on visitors count

Tags: web-hosting, http-server

my site is having around 300 unique visits/5000 pageviews per day.
i want to know how many unique visits/page views (approx.) a site should have to be called
low , moderate and high traffic website.

also how can i test strength of my website, like how many requests my website can process simultaneously.
http://loadimpact.com/ -- iam looking for some tool like this.

i want these figures to choose a proper webhost as my new project is very big as compared to this one.
Also what are the things we should look for when choosing a web host. Ram and CPU are important for webservers to process requests but most of webhosts never talk of cpu and ram allotted to us. They only provide disk space and daily/monthly allowed traffic in GBS.

Comment: "Low", "moderate", and "high" are not technical terms. There is no standard definition for them.

Answer (score 1):

browsermob.com (they have since been renamed) has great tools for actually doing load testing on your site... You can see how much stress it can take before it becomes slow or even crashes.  I would seriously recommend them as one of your tools.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is a good load-testing tool http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/

Make sure you’re allowed to by the hoster / webspace provider, as they may thing it’s a DOS or DDOS attack.

Things to look for… Well, depending on how big your project is you may want to check not only webspace but also vserver or root server hosting, which requires more administration from your side then though. But you’ll have more info about hardware and control over it.

You can always ask hosters on what system they would host you. Shared host? With how many other websites on what system?

If they don’t provide you any info, maybe they have something to hide? :)